# Audit or monitor user login

Tags: security, windows-server-2012-r2

How do you audit or monitor logins and logouts on workstations from a Server 2012 R3 server?

The workstations are Windows 7 and 10, and the people who will be using this aren't the most technologically experienced, so I'd prefer a simple solution.

Comment: Refurb, I've rephrased your question so that it is on-topic and not requesting a software recommendation. Could you EDIT the question further to add what sort of authentication they are using (Domain, local passwords, etc)?

Comment: So.... requesting a software package is against forum policy?

Comment: Correct: https://superuser.com/help/on-topic This is mostly because the "best" software is heavily a matter of personal preference and opinion, and software changes frequently and rapidly, and what may be appropriate at one time will not be the best fit later. There is an SE site dedicated to Software Recommendations to fit this need. However, to audit logon/logoff in a Windows domain you do not need third-party software. And if a question is not specifically asking for a software product, but a specific software product IS a good answer, that is also acceptable.

Comment: You mean Server 2012 **R2**, correct?

Comment: What everyone missed is the fact that the people using it are 1) Not allowed access to the DC and 2) Aren't tremendously computer literate. They need something very simply and very easy to use. Sifting through and trying to assimilate logs wouldn't cut it. Sorry.

Comment: In reference to the first part opinions can be a wonderful thing as long as you realize they are just opinions. Not law. References from other users on both software and hardware can be invaluable as long as you know how to interpret it. So what is the link to the forum that will give you recommendations and opinions?

Answer (score 2):

I usually look on the domain controller the event log security and filter out events related to logon's and logoff's. This will show computer names, IP addresses and times.